# Getting "The Authorization server does not support this response type" from doorkeeper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, doorkeeper

I am trying to build out an api using devise (3.4.1) + doorkeeper (2.4.1) + Rails 4.2 and I keep getting the error "The Authorization server does not support this response type" when I try to connect my front end app Here is the dump from the console:

```
Started GET "/oauth/authorize?response_type=token&client_id=a91f8fea40322739310b0db9ee3e3d53878bff0df073f3aa36af7da4f99b365e&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9000&scope=public&state=" for ::1 at 2015-03-28 16:12:18 -0700
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.9ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
Processing by Doorkeeper::AuthorizationsController#new as HTML
  Parameters: {"response_type"=>"token", "client_id"=>"a91f8fea40322739310b0db9ee3e3d53878bff0df073f3aa36af7da4f99b365e", "redirect_uri"=>"http://localhost:9000", "scope"=>"public", "state"=>""}
  User Load (3.5ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
  Doorkeeper::Application Load (1.1ms)  SELECT  "oauth_applications".* FROM "oauth_applications" WHERE "oauth_applications"."uid" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["uid", "a91f8fea40322739310b0db9ee3e3d53878bff0df073f3aa36af7da4f99b365e"]]
  Rendered /Users/osuthorpe/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/doorkeeper-2.1.4/app/views/doorkeeper/authorizations/error.html.erb within layouts/doorkeeper/application (287.7ms)
Completed 200 OK in 460ms (Views: 406.2ms | ActiveRecord: 11.4ms | Solr: 0.0ms)
```

the front end app is working fine, I can authenticate using other oauth2 providers.

Answer (score 8):

I think new version of doorkeeper may disable some grant_flows. 
You can enable it by remove comment at `grant_flows %w(authorization_code implicit password client_credentials)` in config/initializers/doorkeeper.rb to enable all grant flows